# Can't able to Transfer Data in room DB

Tags: android, database

When I try to click on Add to the category in the Home fragment  the card does not go to the Category fragment

here I am sharing my Home fragment and category fragment code with Dao and the User database of the category fragment

```
package com.trycatch_tanmay.code;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

import com.trycatch_tanmay.ModelHome;

@Database(entities = {ModelHome.class},version = 1)
public  abstract  class Categorydatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract  catgeforyDao getCatDao();
    public static  Categorydatabase INSTANCE;

    public static  Categorydatabase  getINSTANCE(Context context){
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context ,Categorydatabase.class,"categoryDatabase")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
// single ton  classpackage com.trycatch_tanmay.code;

import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;

import com.trycatch_tanmay.ModelHome;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface catgeforyDao {
@Insert
    void  Insert(ModelHome modelHome);

@Query("Select * from ModelHome")
    List<ModelHome>getAllUser();
}
    package com.trycatch_tanmay.code;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import com.trycatch_tanmay.HomeAdapter;
    import com.trycatch_tanmay.ModelHome;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements HomeAdapter.OnFavoriteItemClickListener {

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private HomeAdapter homeAdapter;
        HomeFragment homeFragment;
        private List<ModelHome> modelHomeList = new ArrayList<>();
        private UserDao userDao;
        private FavouriteDatabase favouriteDatabase;
        private FavouriteDao favouriteDao; // Correct initialization
        FavouriteAdapter favouriteAdapter;
        private catgeforyDao catgeforydao;
        private Categorydatabase categorydatabase;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(requireContext(), modelHomeList, favouriteDao, homeFragment,catgeforydao);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);

            // Initialize the FavouriteDatabase instance
            favouriteDatabase = FavouriteDatabase.getInstance(requireContext());
            categorydatabase = Categorydatabase.getINSTANCE(requireContext());
    // Initialize the FavouriteDao instance
            favouriteDao = favouriteDatabase.getfavouriteDao(); // Proper initialization
            catgeforydao = categorydatabase.getCatDao();
    //        ***********************************************
            Userdatabase userDatabase = Userdatabase.getINSTANCE(requireContext());
            userDao = userDatabase.getmodel();

            fetchData();

            // Set the click listener for the HomeAdapter
            homeAdapter.setOnFavoriteItemClickListener(new HomeAdapter.OnFavoriteItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFavoriteItemClick(int position, ModelHome modelHome) {
                    if (favouriteDao != null) {
                        favouriteDao.Insert(modelHome); // Insert the clicked item into the database
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Added to favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    fetchData(); // Refresh data in the FavouriteFragment
                    if (catgeforydao != null) {
                        catgeforydao.Insert(modelHome);
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Added to category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

        private void fetchData() {
            homeAdapter.clearData();
            List<ModelHome> userList = userDao.getAllUsers();
            for (ModelHome modelHome : userList) {
                homeAdapter.addUser(modelHome);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            fetchData();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFavoriteItemClick(int position, ModelHome modelHome) {
    //        handleFavoriteItemClick(position, modelHome);
            // Handle item click in favourites here
            ModelHome clickedItem = modelHomeList.get(position);
            // Implement your logic

            // Call the Insert method to save the clickedItem to the database
            favouriteDao.Insert(clickedItem);

            // Notify the adapter of data change in the FavouriteFragment
            favouriteAdapter.addUser(clickedItem);
        }

    //    public void navigateToCategoryFragment(ModelHome modelHome) {
    //        CategoryFragment categoryFragment = new CategoryFragment();
    //        // Pass the selected ModelHome object to CategoryFragment
    //        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //        bundle.putParcelable("selectedModelHome", modelHome);
    //        categoryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    //        // Navigate to CategoryFragment
    //        getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    //                .replace(R.id.container, categoryFragment)
    //                .addToBackStack(null)
    //                .commit();
    //    }

        private void handleFavoriteItemClick(int position, ModelHome clickedItem) {
    //// ADpter click listern insert query on heart button and  favourtite dao inziale favourite get all
            // Get an instance of FavouriteDao
            FavouriteDao favouriteDao = favouriteDatabase.getfavouriteDao();

            // Call the Insert method to save the clickedItem to the database
            favouriteDao.Insert(clickedItem);

            // Replace the fragment with the FavouriteFragment and pass the clicked item
            Fragment favouriteFragment = new FavouriteFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("clickedItem", clickedItem);
            favouriteFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.favourite_container, favouriteFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        public void navigateToCategoryFragment(ModelHome modelHome) {
            CategoryFragment categoryFragment = new CategoryFragment();
            categoryFragment.addItemToCategory(modelHome); // Pass selected item to CategoryFragment
            // Navigate to CategoryFragment
            getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, categoryFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
        }


    }
package com.trycatch_tanmay.code;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.trycatch_tanmay.ModelHome;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView cat_RVC;
    Categoryadapter categoryadapter;
    catgeforyDao catgeforydao;
    private List<ModelHome> categoryList;
    private Categorydatabase categorydatabase;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
        cat_RVC = view.findViewById(R.id.cat_RVC);
        categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        categoryadapter = new Categoryadapter(requireContext(), categoryList);
        cat_RVC.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2));
        cat_RVC.setAdapter(categoryadapter);
        // Initialize the CategoryDatabase instance and assign it to the global variable
        categorydatabase = Categorydatabase.getINSTANCE(requireContext());
        // Initialize the CategoryDao instance
        catgeforydao = categorydatabase.getCatDao();

        fethData();
        return view;
    }



    private void fethData(){
        categoryadapter.clearData();
        // Fetch data from CategoryDao
        if (catgeforydao != null) {
            List<ModelHome> userList = catgeforydao.getAllUser();
            for (ModelHome modelHome : userList) {
                // Add fetched data to the adapter
                categoryadapter.addUser(modelHome);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        fethData();
    }
    // Method to add selected item to CategoryFragment
    public void addItemToCategory(ModelHome modelHome) {
        if (catgeforydao != null) {
            catgeforydao.Insert(modelHome); // Insert selected item into CategoryDao
            categoryadapter.addUser(modelHome); // Add selected item to RecyclerView
        }
    }
//        catgeforydao.Insert(modelHome); // Insert selected item into CategoryDao
//        categoryadapter.addUser(modelHome); // Add selected item to RecyclerView
    }
```

When clicked on add to category in the home fragment the card should be visible in category fragment When I try to click on Add to the category in the Home fragment  the card does not go to the Category fragment

here I am sharing my Home fragment and category fragment code with Dao and the User database of the category fragment